# Convert array in string with another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a two array first is:

```
$array1 = ['settings:rules:key','settings:scrum:way:other'];
```

I have explode `$array1`:

```
$temp_array = explode(":",$array1);
```

Now I have another array:

```
$array2 = [settings] => Array
        (  [rules] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 
                            [showValueField] => 1
                     ) 
                )
```

something like this.

I need to access second array with key given in first array like:

```
$array2['settings']['rules']['key']
```

I have to get this keys from first array after explode

Comment: You have a problem in that `$array2['settings']['rules']` doesn't have an element `['key']`, it has an element `[0]['key']`

Comment: i need to get keys from first array and access second array. can you write a code

Comment: Your second array keys don't follow the values in the first array. Your first array value would need to be `'settings:rules:0:key'` to match your second array.

Comment: You also can't explode an array you'd need to explode each value

Comment: can you give a perfect solution. i'll get keys in array to access another array. i there any way to do it.

Comment: @Coder Did my post helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this kind of loop:

```
function getVal($path, $arr) {
    $current = $arr[array_shift($path)];
    while (count($path)) {
        $key = array_shift($path);
        if (!is_array($current) || !isset($current[$key]))
            return false; // protect against non-existing keys
        $current = $current[$key];
    }
    return $current;
}

//example used:
$arr = array("settings" => array("rules" => array("key" => "AAA")));
echo getVal(explode(":",'settings:rules:key'), $arr) . PHP_EOL;
```